# How to remove previous content from cell

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ios7

I have tableview with searchbar. I am displaying number of data in cell. And I am creating cell using xib. I am also adding two button in cell. Now when I search anything in search bar at that time table is reloading and cell button are adding again on that place.
See below screens shots:
1)First time created tableview:

[image]

2)After search data:

```
![enter image description here][2]
```

[image]

My code for This:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
WorkDetailCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"WorkDetailCell"];
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *topLevelObject;
    topLevelObject = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"WorkDetailCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [topLevelObject objectAtIndex:0];
    cell.backgroundColor=RGB(210, 200, 191);
    cell.selectedBackgroundView=[self selectedCellView];
}

if(search==FALSE){
    NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);
    cell.clearsContextBeforeDrawing=YES;
    //NSDictionary *detailList=[tempDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSArray *temp=[tempDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lblOrganization.text=[temp objectAtIndex:1];//@"TGB";//[detailList valueForKey:@"organizationName"];
    cell.lblAddress.text=[temp objectAtIndex:2];//@"Ahmedabad";//detailList[@"address"];
    cell.lblLandmark.text=[temp objectAtIndex:3];//@"SG HighWay";//detailList[@"landmark"];
    cell.lblCity.text=[temp objectAtIndex:4];//@"Ahmedabad";//detailList[@"city"];
    cell.lblState.text=[temp objectAtIndex:5];//@"Ahmedabad";//detailList[@"state"];


    UIButton *doneButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    doneButton.frame=CGRectMake(220, 45, 100, 60);
  //[doneButton setTitle:@"pick" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doneButtonClicked:) fo rControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pick"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [doneButton setTag:indexPath.row];
   UIButton *previewButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    previewButton.frame=CGRectMake(235, 15, 65, 30);
    [previewButton setTitle:@"Preview" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [previewButton setTitleColor:RGB(110, 73, 44) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [previewButton addTarget:self action:@selector(previewButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [previewButton setTag:indexPath.row];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:doneButton];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:previewButton];
}
else{
 //   NSDictionary *detailList=[searchResultArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   // NSLog(@"dic%@",detailList);
    //cell.contentView.clearsContextBeforeDrawing=YES;
  cell.clearsContextBeforeDrawing=YES;
    NSArray *temp=[searchResultArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lblOrganization.text= [temp objectAtIndex:1]; //[detailList valueForKey:@"organizationName"];
    cell.lblAddress.text=[temp objectAtIndex:2];//detailList[@"address"];
    cell.lblLandmark.text=[temp objectAtIndex:3];//detailList[@"landmark"];
    cell.lblCity.text=[temp objectAtIndex:4];//detailList[@"city"];
    cell.lblState.text=[temp objectAtIndex:5];//detailList[@"state"];
    UIButton *doneButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    doneButton.frame=CGRectMake(220, 45, 100, 60);
  //[doneButton setTitle:@"pick" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doneButtonClicked:) fo rControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pick"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [doneButton setTag:indexPath.row];
   UIButton *previewButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    previewButton.frame=CGRectMake(235, 15, 65, 30);
    [previewButton setTitle:@"Preview" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [previewButton setTitleColor:RGB(110, 73, 44) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [previewButton addTarget:self action:@selector(previewButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [previewButton setTag:indexPath.row];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:doneButton];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:previewButton];
   }
   return cell;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `nil` values you want to get rid off or insert repeatable code to reusability `if` (this is this: `if (cell == nil) {`

The major rule here is creating a cell you have to separate two kinds of object:
- the objects unique to every cell (ex texts)
- the repetitive objects (mainly style objects such as color, background, shadows, buttons and stuff)

The first group should be outside reusability "if" `(cell == nil)`. The second one should be inside.

In your case:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
WorkDetailCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"WorkDetailCell"];
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *topLevelObject;
    topLevelObject = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"WorkDetailCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [topLevelObject objectAtIndex:0];
    cell.backgroundColor=RGB(210, 200, 191);
    cell.selectedBackgroundView=[self selectedCellView];

   UIButton *doneButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    doneButton.frame=CGRectMake(220, 45, 100, 60);
  //[doneButton setTitle:@"pick" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doneButtonClicked:) fo rControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pick"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [doneButton setTag:indexPath.row];
   UIButton *previewButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    previewButton.frame=CGRectMake(235, 15, 65, 30);
    [previewButton setTitle:@"Preview" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [previewButton setTitleColor:RGB(110, 73, 44) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [previewButton addTarget:self action:@selector(previewButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:doneButton];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:previewButton];
}

if(search==FALSE){
    NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);
    cell.clearsContextBeforeDrawing=YES;
    //NSDictionary *detailList=[tempDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSArray *temp=[tempDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lblOrganization.text=[temp objectAtIndex:1];//@"TGB";//[detailList valueForKey:@"organizationName"];
    cell.lblAddress.text=[temp objectAtIndex:2];//@"Ahmedabad";//detailList[@"address"];
    cell.lblLandmark.text=[temp objectAtIndex:3];//@"SG HighWay";//detailList[@"landmark"];
    cell.lblCity.text=[temp objectAtIndex:4];//@"Ahmedabad";//detailList[@"city"];
    cell.lblState.text=[temp objectAtIndex:5];//@"Ahmedabad";//detailList[@"state"];


    [previewButton setTag:indexPath.row];

}
else{
 //   NSDictionary *detailList=[searchResultArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   // NSLog(@"dic%@",detailList);
    //cell.contentView.clearsContextBeforeDrawing=YES;
  cell.clearsContextBeforeDrawing=YES;
    NSArray *temp=[searchResultArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lblOrganization.text= [temp objectAtIndex:1]; //[detailList valueForKey:@"organizationName"];
    cell.lblAddress.text=[temp objectAtIndex:2];//detailList[@"address"];
    cell.lblLandmark.text=[temp objectAtIndex:3];//detailList[@"landmark"];
    cell.lblCity.text=[temp objectAtIndex:4];//detailList[@"city"];
    cell.lblState.text=[temp objectAtIndex:5];//detailList[@"state"];

    [previewButton setTag:indexPath.row];
   }
   return cell;
```

Comment: ok i want exactly same thing...thank you..and i got your point

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code:

1. You set tag for `doneButton` and `previewButton` but the tag never be used. So what the tag is using for?
2. The table view cell will be reused when you scroll the table view. For example, if the cell appears at index 0 is reused at index 10, as your code, the buttons will be added again.

So, you can set a unique tag separately for all buttons, and every time `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is called, you should check if the button has be added, if so, you should avoid adding buttons again.

You can add code like follows:

```
    if (![cell viewWithTag:YOUR_BUTTON_TAG]) {
        //create and add your button
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

when you reload the tableview , you will need to remove the buttons which are added as subview 
so in your`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{`

just call `[cell.contentView removeSubViews];`

This should help

Comment: He dosent need reusability, if you understand its not the matter of  reusability he is adding the content every time so you can just remove the things which are not needed, so the button will not get added twice as in the picture

Comment: Everyone needs reusability! If you style your cell every time there will be horrible lagging in scrolling. Changing text every time sure, redrawing button - no!